# Equation of a plane, given two points and a perpendicular plane

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

> The plane passes through the points $(3, 4, 1)$ and $(3, 1, -6)$ and is perpendicular to the plane $7x + 9y + 4z = 17$. Find the equation of the plane.

What I was thinking was to take the cross product of the normal $(7, 9, 4)$ and the line $(3-3, 4-1, 1-(-6)) = (0, 3, 7)$. However, when I get the answer of $51x - 49y + 21z = 0$, it is not accepted as the right answer. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change "$=0$" to something else in order to have the plane pass trough $(3,4,1)$

Comment: $(7,9,4)$ is a vector, not a plane.

Comment: Also, the cross product is $(51,-49,21)$. The 49 is negative.

Comment: You did good (apart from computing errors: I did not check)  but you found just the normal to the plane: then you have to take a plane with that normal **and passing** through one of the points given (not through the origin).

Comment: Thank you all! The biggest mistake was that the cross product was indeed (51, -49, 21) and I needed to solve using (3, 4, 1) which made the equation equal to -22.

Answer (score 1):

make the ansatz the plane has the equation
$$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ then we have
$$3a+4b+c+d=0$$(1)
$$3a+b-6c+d=0$$ (2)
and
$$[a,b,c]\cdot[7,9,4]=0$$ (3)
can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The normal to the plane is perpendicular to $ (3,4,1) - (3,1,-6) = (0, 3, 7) $ and also perpendicular to $(7,9,4) $, so it is along their cross product:

$N = (0, 3, 7) \times (7, 9, 4) = (-51, 49, -21) $

The plane passes through $(3,4,1)$ hence its equation is

$ (-51, 49, -21) \cdot ( (x, y, z) - (3, 4, 1) ) = 0 $

and this simplifies to

$ (-51, 49, -21) \cdot (x, y, z) = 22$

That is,

$ 51 x - 49 y + 21 z + 22 = 0 $